# PHP "XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity"

Tags: php, xml, api

My API processor returns data in one of several formats designated by the "type' keyword in the request. I am able to invoke, for instance, a JSON header using the following method, but this does not work for XML. Is there a way of invoking this without producing an error?

```
<?PHP
if($_REQUEST['type'] == "XML")
{
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");
}
```

There is no white space in the header designation.
Later down the line, I am using PHP's dom class to formulate the XML.
This looks like this

```
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0", 'utf-8');
$root = $dom->createElement("Data");
$dom->appendChild($root);
if(!empty($Error))
{
    $Er = $dom->createElement("Errors");
    $root->appendChild($Er);
    foreach($Error as $value)
    {
        $key = "Error";
        $Child = $dom->createElement($key);
        $Child = $Er->appendChild($Child);
        $data = $dom->createTextNode($value);
        $data = $Child->appendChild($data);
    }
}
else
{
    foreach($XMLItems as $key => $value)
    {
        $key = $dom->createElement($key);
        $root->appendChild($key);
        $variable = $dom->createTextNode($value);
        $key->appendChild($variable);
    }
}
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$dom->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

**Solution:** What I did to solve the problem here, following aynber's suggestions, is to eliminate any blank lines in the PHP as well as any includes. I eliminated closing PHP tags and extra lines in those includes as well as the main file. This eliminated the two blank lines at the top of the file, allowing me to insert the XML header. Whether eliminating the closing tags was necessary may be questionable, but they do not need to be there.

Comment: The error isn't coming from that, but from the data you're returning. The client is expecting a valid XML, and apparently what they're getting back does not start with actual XML. It could be white space, or something else invalid. Look at the response to see what it's getting back.

Comment: @aynber I added more information to my question above.

Comment: You may, you may not. Double-check the response from the server, see exactly what it shows at the beginning of the response.

Comment: There are definitely two blank lines at the beginning of the response. Not sure where they are coming from. Nothing is being written between the top of the file and the XML process. There is considerable PHP processing going on between. No space before line enders. Blank lines, maybe?

Comment: Possibly blank lines. Double-check for any blank lines or empty/null characters at the top of the PHP files before `<?php`, and any place you might be breaking out of it.

Comment: What is `$XMLItems`?

Comment: XMLItems is an array of key-value pairs. It is the content of the XML.

Comment: Lost my time to edit last comment. The URL is parsed, the resulting variables are processed, They are sent to a mainframe via an API, the result is further processed and the array is created from the results. Response is returned as HTML, XML, or JSON depending on the requestor's choice.

Comment: The problem is that it's impossible to replicate the problem without a short, representative sample of `$XMLItems`.

Comment: $XMLItems = array('Variable_One'=>$VariableOne,'Variable_Two''=>$VariableTwo,'Variable_Three'=>$VariableThree.. etc.

Comment: This is not helpful - you just moved the goalposts and now we need to know what `$VariableOne`, `$VariableTwo`, etc. look like. Remember, you can't be helped unless the issue can be reproduced on someone else's system. Also, make these changes to the question itself, not in the comments.

Comment: @aynber - please post your suggestions as the answer to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity"` means that somewhere at the start of your XML output, there is a space or other character that's not supposed to be there. There are a few places to check:

- The beginning of every PHP file. Make sure there are no spaces, new lines, or invisible characters before `<?php`
- Any place you break out of and back into the PHP blocks. Anything there will be sent to the browser, even if it is white space.